# making tic tac toe, code is complete without error messages but wont run?

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

This is my first project, I used a lot of resources from others with the same project and this is what I have come up with. I am using Jupyter notebook. I am not getting any more error messages in my code, but for some reason I can't get it to run? Also, any advice or improvements in my code would also be appreciated.

I've tried to just call the tic_tac_toe() command but nothing comes up and I'm not sure why.

```
def tic_tac_toe():
    brd = [None] + list(range(1,10)) 
    end = False
    winner = ((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(1,4,7),(2,5,8),(3,6,9),(1,5,9),    (3,5,7))
    from IPython.display import clear_output
    def show_board():
        print(brd[1]+'|'+brd[2]+'|'+brd[3])
        print(brd[4]+'|'+brd[5]+'|'+brd[6])
        print(brd[7]+'|'+brd[8]+'|'+brd[9])
        print()
    def player_input():
        marker = ''
        while marker != 'x' and marker != 'o':
            marker = input('Do you want to be x or o?: ')
        player1 = marker
        if player1 == 'x':
            player2 ='o'
        else:
            player2 = 'x'
        player_markers = [player1,player2]
    def choose_number():
         while True:
                try:
                    val = int(input())
                    if val in brd:
                        return val
                   else:
                        print('\n Please choose another number')
                except ValueError:
                    print('\n Please choose another number')
    def game_over():
        for a, b, c in winner:
            if brd[a] == brd[b] == brd[c]:
                print("{0} wins!\n".format(board[a]))
                print("Congrats\n")
                return True
        if 9 == sum((pos == 'x' or pos == 'o') for pos in board):
            print("The game ends in a tie\n")
            return True
        for player in 'x' or 'o' * 9:
            draw()
            if is_game_over():
                break
            print("{0} pick your move".format(player))
            brd[choose_number()] = player
            print()
    while True:
        tac_tac_toe()
        if input("Play again (y/n)\n") != "y":
            break
```

I'm not sure why it is not running normally.

Comment: Do you actually have all the functions inside `tic_tac_toe`? And do you ever call `tic_tac_toe`? That loop at the bottom is inside of the function at posted here.

Comment: The last `while True` loop... is the indentation for that correct? It's in the `tac_tac_toe` function

Comment: You never actually call `choose_number` to get user input

Comment: Note the "minimal" part of [mre] guidelines -- we ask that you provide only the **shortest possible** code needed for others to reproduce  a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple things wrong with your code here. Your indentation for one. Also wondering why your functions are all in another function. You also create a bunch of functions but never call most of them. And have some functions that do not seem to exist. There are also a lot of logic errors here and there.

Try this instead:

```
# numpy is a package that has a lot of helpful functions and lets you manipulate
# numbers and arrays in many more useful ways than the standard Python list allows you to
import numpy as np

def show_board(brd):
    print(brd[0]+'|'+brd[1]+'|'+brd[2])
    print(brd[3]+'|'+brd[4]+'|'+brd[5])
    print(brd[6]+'|'+brd[7]+'|'+brd[8])
    print()

def player_input():
    marker = ''
    while marker != 'x' and marker != 'o':
        marker = input('Do you want to be x or o?: ')
    player1 = marker
    if player1 == 'x':
        player2 ='o'
    else:
        player2 = 'x'
    player_markers = [player1,player2]
    return player_markers

def choose_number(brd):
    while True:
        try:
            val = int(input())
            if brd[val-1] == "_":
                return val
            else:
                print('\nNumber already taken. Please choose another number:')
        except ValueError:
            print('\nYou did not enter a number. Please enter a valid number:')

def is_game_over(winner, brd):
    for a, b, c in winner:
        if brd[a] != "_" and (brd[a] == brd[b] == brd[c]):
            print("{} wins!\n".format(brd[a]))
            print("Congrats\n")
            return True
    if 9 == sum((pos == 'x' or pos == 'o') for pos in brd):
        print("The game ends in a tie\n")
        return True

# I split this function in two because the "is_game_over" code was included here
# instead of being by itself.         
def game_over(winner, brd, player_markers):
    last = 0
    # The first player is the one stored in "player_markers[0]"
    player = player_markers[0]
    # There are nine turns so that is what this is for. It has nothing to do with
    # 'x' or 'o'. And one more turn is added for the "is_game_over" to work in 
    # case of a tie.
    for i in range(10):
        if is_game_over(winner, brd):
            break
        print()
        print("{0} pick your move [1-9]:".format(player))
        brd[choose_number(brd)-1] = player
        show_board(brd)
        # This is added to change from one player to another 
        # by checking who was the last one (look up ternary operators)
        player = player_markers[1] if last==0 else player_markers[0]
        last = 1 if last==0 else 0

def tic_tac_toe():
    brd = ["_"] * 9 
    end = False
    winner = ((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(1,4,7),(2,5,8),(3,6,9),(1,5,9),(3,5,7))
    winner = np.array([list(elem) for elem in winner]) - 1
    player_markers = player_input()
    show_board(brd)
    game_over(winner, brd, player_markers)


while True:
    tic_tac_toe()
    if input("Play again (y/n)\n") != "y":
        break
```

Comment: Just to help me better understand what exactly is going on in this new improved code, could you please explain a few lines to me?
I’ve seen multiple users making tic tac toe indent their whole code underneath one function as I tried to do, could you please explain to me why that was the wrong way to go about that?
What does import numpy as np do?
Lastly, I don’t exactly understand whats happening in the game_over function, if you wouldn’t mind breaking that down.

Comment: @Bran You can totally indent everything and have it all inside your `tic_tac_toe` function but I would make that a class instead then. I just took it out as I did not see the necessity of it, not because it was wrong. See my comments for the numpy line and this [link](https://numpy.org/). I am just adding that package to the file so I can use the `np.array` method in `tic_tac_toe`. See my comments for the `game_over` function.